# Button single click not working, double click works

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview

I'm working with android recyclerview. I have a button on each item. When I click first time to button, nothing happens but I click double to this button, it works.
Bellow, this is my code:

```
public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

@BindView(R.id.image_news)
public ImageView imageNews;

@BindView(R.id.text_title_news)
public TextView textTitleNews;

@BindView(R.id.text_description_news)
public TextView textDescriptionNews;

@BindView(R.id.text_time)
public TextView textTime;

@BindView(R.id.button_share)
public Button buttonShare;

@BindView(R.id.button_save)
public Button buttonSave;

public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    buttonShare.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == buttonSave.getId()) {
        Log.e("clicked", "save");
    } else if (v.getId() == buttonShare.getId()) {
        Log.e("clicked", "share");
    }
}
```

}

Please help!!!

Comment: use switch case for this.

Comment: if switch case doesn't work, initialize an OnClickListener anonymously for both the buttons... that will definitely work out

Answer (score 0):

try out initializing each onclicklistener anonymously as follows:

```
buttonShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //do something 

   }

});

buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //do something else

   }

});
```

If you want to avoid this, you can try using a switch case instead of the if statements

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

@BindView(R.id.image_news)
public ImageView imageNews;

@BindView(R.id.text_title_news)
public TextView textTitleNews;

@BindView(R.id.text_description_news)
public TextView textDescriptionNews;

@BindView(R.id.text_time)
public TextView textTime;

@BindView(R.id.button_share)
public Button buttonShare;

@BindView(R.id.button_save)
public Button buttonSave;

public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    buttonShare.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_share:
            Log.e("clicked", "share");
            break;
        case R.id.button_save:
            Log.e("clicked", "saved");
            break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ButterKnife I would recommend you to use ButterKnife annotation for performing click actions on button

```
@OnClick({R.id.button_share, R.id.button_save})
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_share:
            // Do something
            break;
        case R.id.button_save:
            // Do something
            break;
    }
}
```

And use switch instead of if, for better readability.